# Change the visibility of usercontrols as per the enum

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, user-controls

I have created an enum

```
  public enum TaskVal
    {
    NotStarted,
    InProgress,
    Completed
    }
```

Now i have created a user control in xaml with textbox. I have maintained all the xaml binding path. This looks something like

```
<ListView  Name="ListOfTasks"  BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <userControls:Work Task="{Binding TaskValue=TaskValues}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Backend of implemented c# model is

```
 public class TaskModel
 {
    public TaskVal TaskValues {get;set;}
 }
```

This is the implemented login inside a xaml page

```
List<TaskVal> _list=new List<TaskVal>();
_list.Add(new TaskModel(){TaskValues=TaskVal.NotStarted});
_list.Add(new TaskModel(){TaskValues=TaskVal.InProgress});
_list.Add(new TaskModel(){TaskValues=TaskVal.NotStarted});
_list.Add(new TaskModel(){TaskValues=TaskVal.Completed});
_list.Add(new TaskModel(){TaskValues=TaskVal.InProgress});
_list.Add(new TaskModel(){TaskValues=TaskVal.NotStarted});

ListOfTasks.ItemsSource=_list;
```

and inside the usercontrol i defined the dependency property

```
public TaskVal TaskValue
{
    get 
    {
       return (TaskVal)GetValue(TaskValueProperty);
    }
    set
    {
       CheckTextBoxes();
       SetValue(TaskValueProperty, value);
     }
 }



public static readonly DependencyProperty TaskValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TaskValue", typeof(TaskVal),
              typeof(WorkUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(TaskVal.NotStarted));
```

and CheckTextBoxes function is Something like this

```
public void CheckTextBoxes()
{
   switch(TaskValue)
   {
      case NotStarted:
         Textbox1.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
         TextBox2.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
         TextBox3.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
         break;
      case InProgress:
         Textbox1.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
         TextBox2.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
         TextBox3.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
         break;
      case Completed:
         Textbox1.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
         TextBox2.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
         TextBox3.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
         break;
      default:
         break;

   }
}
```

The thing is it just uses the default value of TaskVal Enum. Other value of TaskVal doesnot work. Is there something i need to be aware of?

Comment: When you write `Task="{Binding TaskValue=TaskValues}"` you probably meant to write `TaskValue="{Binding Path=TaskValues}"`?

Comment: Besides that, you should not call anything else than the `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods in the getter and setter of a CLR wrapper of a dependency property (i.e. your `CheckTextBoxes()` call). The reason is explained in [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.100).aspx). Instead, register a PropertyChangedCallback with the property's metadada.

Comment: @Clemens yeah i meant the TaskValue. But how do i change the visibility of the other text boxes? i have tried even the individual call. But there is no luck in it. Can you suggest me some ideas?

Comment: when are you calling this CheckTextBoxes() method? I mean from where at what point?

Comment: @KyloRen I thought maybe while binding the usercontrol, the TaskValue calls the CheckTextBoxes(), and after calling the respective textboxes visibility can be changed accordingly.

Comment: @ChandanGupta do it after the  SetValue(TaskValueProperty, value);

Comment: @KyloRen I have done it already. but it doesnot seem to work.

Comment: @KyloRen I have done this by calling the CheckTextBoxes() after the user control is loaded.

Comment: @ChandanGupta I'm very confused about your class hierarchy right now.. where you have defined TaskValue and what role is _list every item has in visibility, so can't comment anything

Comment: @KyloRen _list is the list of model that is binded with ListView in xaml. This _list is populated from db to make the visibility of textboxes. I was calling it without initialization of object. I was making mistake to call function in constructor. The function needs to be called only after the object is created. The above code works too.

Comment: @ChandanGupta CheckTextBoxes() is now being called inside UserControl_Loaded methos, that means one time and it's dependent on TaskValue property which is of usercontrol, so how is this function is controlling ListView 's item's visibility which is bound to _list (i guess)?

Comment: @KyloRen My main concern was to load settings when the object is created. I checked by changing the value in run time. That did the trick. But it didnot behaved same when the object is created. So i called the function after the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

CheckTextBoxes() can be called only after complete loading of user control i.e. this function is called on usercontrol_loaded().

```
private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckTextBoxes();
        }
```